# dotnet equivalent for VB methods

Tags: vb6-migration

how can we identify a method if its dotnet specific or VB specific? Or how can we know what is the dot net equivalent method for a particular vb method ?    Please help...

Eg:StrComp( "", "" )  is a VB specific
   String.Equals("", "") is a .NET specific

Answer (score 1):

Check it's [namespace and assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.strcomp.aspx).

```
Namespace:  Microsoft.VisualBasic
Assembly:   Microsoft.VisualBasic (in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll)
```

In general unless it's a VB keyword or compiler specific entity, then you should able to use the functions from any .net language.